# Android Studio React Native App results in red screen

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, react-native

this is my first question, though I frequent stack overflow all the time.

I followed this setup via facebook: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I'm trying to learn how to make react-native mobile apps. It's also my first time dealing with apps.

I setup android studio (including sdk and emulator), node.js, watchman, react native, etc. Everything listed there except Gradle Daemon, which android studio takes care of when I import the react-native project.

So, I create a project via `react-native init AwesomeProject` as in the example. I start the server with `react-native start` and run the android project via `react-native run-android`.

I have my phone (LGV10, Android 6.0) attached to the PC (Ubuntu 14.04).

Everything builds great.

Then as the app appears on the screen, I get this blaring error that I have spent days searching, testing, and trying to get pass.

[image: App error screenshot]

Does anyone know what this might mean?

I have verified that `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` successfully runs. I don't know what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like your phone is not able to establish a connection to your development server. What does `adb devices` display?

Comment: adb reverse only works on Android 5.0 +

Comment: After you run `react-native start`, it should keep running the server. When you do `react-native run-android` in another terminal, is the server still running? (I had a similar problem because the server crashed.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ur ip address for connecting to development server which means the machine on which you are developing follow below steps :

Step 1 : type `adb shell input keyevent 82` which will bring up pop up shown below :

[image]

> Choose last option :

[image]

> And finally insert ipaddress:8081

for example `10.4.3.252:8081`

[image]

Note that do not put localhost it may not work , so insert ip:port

once you are done with above steps , again go back to app and choose reload option from dev settings which comes from pop up `adb shell input keyevent 82`

Please see this articles from offical [react-native saying how to connect to development server](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html)

If you are planing to deploy on production then you would not require development server for that you have to sign apk , please read this articles from [react-native offical site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Comment: If you are connecting the Phone via USB, then use `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`